# Calculating distances between vectors of two numpy arrays

Tags: numpy, array-broadcasting

I have two numpy arrays **R** with dimensions *S x F*  and **W** with dimensions *N x M x F*. Getting concrete lets assign the following values `N = 5`, `M = 7`, `F = 3`, `S = 4`

The array **R** contains a collections of samples `S = 4` with `F = 3` features. Each line represents a samples and each row a feature. Therefore `R[0]` is the first sample, `R[1]` the second and goes on. Each `R[i-th]` entry, contains `F` elements, giving for sake of example `R[0] = np.array([1, 4, -2])`.

Here is a small snippet to initialize all those values, with a MWE in mind

```
import numpy as np

# Size of Map (rows, columns)
N, M = 5, 7

# Number of features
F = 3

# Sample size
S = 4

np.random.seed(13)
R = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(S, F))
W = np.random.randint(-4, 5, size=(N, M, F))
```

We can also see a given "depth line" of *numpy array* **W**, as a vector also with same dimension as each row of array **R** (this can easily be noticed looking at the size of the last dimension of both arrays). With that I can access `W[2, 3]` and obtain `np.array([ 2, 2, -1 ])` (the values here are just examples).

I created a simple function to calculate the distance of a given vector **r** to each **"depth line"** of matrix **W** and the return the position of the nearest element of **W** depth line to **r**

```
def nearest_vector_matrix_naive(r, W):
    delta = np.zeros((N,M), dtype=int)
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(M):
            norm = 0
            for k in range(F):
                norm += (r[k] - W[i,j,k])**2
            delta[i,j] = norm
            norm = 0
    win_idx = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(delta, axis=None), delta.shape)
    return win_idx
```

Of course this is a very naive approach, that I could further optimize to the code below, obtaining a HUGE performance boost.

```
def nearest_vector_matrix(r, W):
    delta = np.sum((W[:,:] - r)**2, axis=2)
    return np.unravel_index(np.argmin(delta, axis=None), delta.shape)
```

I can use this function simple as

```
nearest_idx = nearest_vector_matrix(R[0], W)
# Returns the nearest vector in W to R[0]
W[nearest_idx]
```

Since I have the array **R** with a bunch of samples I use the following snippet to calculate the nearest vectors to a array of samples:

```
def nearest_samples_matrix(R, W):
    DELTA = np.zeros((R.shape[0],2))
    for idx, r in enumerate(R):
        delta = np.sum((W[:,:] - r)**2, axis=2)
        DELTA[idx] = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(delta, axis=None), delta.shape)
    return DELTA
```

This function returns an array with **S** rows (**S** being the number of samples) of 2d indexes. That is DELTA has `(S, 2)` shape (always).

I would like to know how can I substitute the `for` loop (for example for a broadcasting) inside `nearest_samples_matrix` to enhance the code execution performance even further?

I could not figure out how to do it. (besides I was able to do it in the first case)

Comment: What is the real size of the arrays? eg. your parameter F? If F is quite small a Kdtree approach will be much faster than all of this brute-force algorithms.https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html

Comment: yes. F is much smaller than S, N or M. In fact talking about Magnitudes: S >> N = M >> F,

Comment: But F can be large as 100. Reading documentation F's larger than 20 are not better than brute force.

Comment: If K-Dtree is at least as fast as brute force approach I can use it globally, and get some benefit when F dimension is small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The best solution depends on the input size of the arrays

For lower dimensional problems dim<20 or less, [a kdtree approach](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html) is usually the way to go. There are quite a lot of answers regarding this topic eg. [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60081384/4045774) I have written a few weeks ago.

If the dimension of the problems is too high you can switch to brute-force algorithms. Both of the following algorithms are much faster than your optimized approach, but on larger input sizes and low dimensional problems much slower than a kdtree approach O(log(n)) instead of O(n^2).

**Brute force 1**

The following example uses an algorithm described [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances.html). It is very fast on large dimensional problems because most of the calculation is done in a highly optimized matrix-matrix multiplication algorithm. 
The disadvantage is high memory usage (all distances are calculated in one function call) and precision problems, because of the more error prone calculation method.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances

def nearest_samples_matrix_2(R,W):
    R_Temp=R
    W_Temp=W.reshape(-1,W.shape[2])
    dist=euclidean_distances(R_Temp, W_Temp)
    ind_1,ind_2=np.unravel_index(np.argmin(dist,axis=1),shape=(W.shape[0],W.shape[1]))
    return np.vstack((ind_1,ind_2)).T
```

**Brute force 2**

This is quite similar to your naive approach, but uses a JIT-Compiler (Numba) to get good performance. Temporary arrays are not necessary and the precision should be good (as long as no overflow occurs). There is room for further optimization (loop tiling) on larger input sizes.

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

#parallelization is only beneficial on larger input data
@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True,cache=True)
def nearest_samples_matrix_3(r, W):
    ind_i=0
    ind_j=0
    out=np.empty((r.shape[0],2),dtype=np.int64)
    for x in nb.prange(r.shape[0]):
        delta=0
        for k in range(W.shape[2]):
            delta += (r[x,k] - W[0,0,k])**2

        for i in range(W.shape[0]):
            for j in range(W.shape[1]):
                norm = 0
                for k in range(W.shape[2]):
                    norm += (r[x,k] - W[i,j,k])**2
                if norm < delta:
                    delta=norm
                    ind_i=i
                    ind_j=j
        out[x,0]=ind_i
        out[x,1]=ind_j
    return out
```

**Timings**

```
#small Arrays
N, M = 100, 200
F = 30
S = 50
R = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(S, F))
W = np.random.randint(-4, 5, size=(N, M, F))

#your function
%timeit nearest_samples_matrix(R,W)
#268 ms ± 2.94 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit nearest_samples_matrix_2(R,W)
#5.62 ms ± 22.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit nearest_samples_matrix_3(R,W)
#3.68 ms ± 1.01 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

#larger arrays
N, M = 1_000, 2_000
F = 50
S = 100
R = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(S, F))
W = np.random.randint(-4, 5, size=(N, M, F))

#%timeit nearest_samples_matrix_1(R,W)
#too slow
%timeit nearest_samples_matrix_2(R,W)
#2.76 s ± 17.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit nearest_samples_matrix_3(R,W)
#1.42 s ± 402 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: I'm receiving this message from numba: NumbaWarning: Cannot cache compiled function "nearest_samples_matrix_3" as it uses dynamic globals (such as ctypes pointers and large global arrays)

Comment: @Lin Which Numba version are you using `nb.__version__` ? At least on 0.48 it should work. But anyway if the function is really performance critical and called quite often, there is only at the first call a overhead of about 800ms (parallel=True) and much less if parallelization is turned off.